# How to modify value of a variable in awk with gsub and print it out?

Tags: linux, awk

I try to cut out a numerical value in a specific column in a specific line. To get the column I use:

```
awk '/REGEX1/{for(i=1;i<=NF;++i)if($i~/REGEX2/)print $i}' $file
```

The output is as desired:

```
executionTime="120"
```

But I'm just interested in the numerical value. If I use

```
awk '/REGEX1/{for(i=1;i<=NF;++i)if($i~/REGEX2/)print $i}' $file | awk '{gsub(/[^0-9]/,""); print}')
```

or

```
awk 'BEGIN{sedcmd="sed 's/[^0-9]//g'"} /REGEX1{for(i=1;i<=NF;++i)if($i~/REGEX2/) print $i | sedcmd}' tmpfile
```

it works. But as soon as I try to use sub(), gsub() or gensub() within an action block it fails. For example with:

```
awk '/REGEX1/{for(i=1;i<=NF;++i)if($i~/REGEX2/)print gsub(/[^0-9]/,"",$i)$i}' $file
```

the output is 7.

What am I doing wrong?

```
gawk -V
GNU Awk 4.1.3, API: 1.1 (GNU MPFR 3.1.5, GNU MP 6.1.1)
```

Comment: provide sample input

Comment: Krischa, honestly saying you are making it complicated. So please post the sample Inputs and expected output so that we could help you in same, rather than guessing each time it is good to let us know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `gsub` function prints the [number of substitutions made](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#String-Functions). That is why you get a number even after removing every numeric character in `$i`.

You should use:

```
if ($i~/REGEX2/) { gsub(/[^0-9]/,"",$i); print $i}
```

Answer (score 3):

You want:

```
awk '/REGEX1/{ for(i=1;i<=NF;++i) if($i~/REGEX2/){x=$i; gsub(/[^0-9]/,"",x); print x}'
```

or gawk-only:

```
awk '/REGEX1/{ for(i=1;i<=NF;++i) if($i~/REGEX2/){print gensub(/[^0-9]/,"","g",$i)}'
```

check the man pages for both functions.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk you could use `gensub` that returns the modified string:

```
{ print gensub(/[^0-9]/, "", "g", $i) }
```